# insert conditional statements in readable streams of process.stdin

Tags: javascript, node.js, stdin

Well, I'm trying to pass a simple if statement to a process.stdin readable stream in NodeJS. But it doesn't seem working. Here's the code :

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null && chunk == 'foo') {
    process.stdout.write('true\n');
} else if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('false\n');
}
```

Does anyone know, what am I doing wrong here? I also tried `chunk == 'foo\n'` but, had no luck. The only time it works is when I set chunk value to a number, like `chunk == 10`.

Comment: What does "it doesn't seem [to be] working" mean? What is the input? What is the actual value of `chunk`? (What do you get when you do `console.log(chunk)`)?

Comment: When you type 'foo' on process.stdin then the chunk is `<Buffer 66 6f 6f 0a>` so you may use  `if(chunk.toString()==='foo\n')` which gives `true`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that the chunk is of Buffer type, and not a string. You can use chunk.toString() to make it a string, and then compare it with `foo\n` (if on linux) or `foo\r\n` (if on windows) and it would work

So your code would look something like this:

```
process.stdin.on('readable', function() {
  var chunk = process.stdin.read();
  if (chunk !== null && chunk.toString() == 'foo\n' || 'foo\r\n') {
    process.stdout.write('true\n');
  } else if (chunk !== null) {
    process.stdout.write('false\n');
  }
});
```